# What could be the reason for firebase to show great unexplained amounts of reads?

Tags: reactjs, google-cloud-firestore, async-await

I am developing a chrome extension that reads data from firestore, in the last few days, i'd finish a day's work with a maximum of 50 reads, today for some reason it is showing a whopping 34K reads, how can I fix this error?

This is my code

```
useEffect(() => {
    const getNotes = () => {
      db.collection("Users")
        .doc(user.email)
        .collection("Notes")
        .get()
        .then((snapshot) => {
          const loadedNotes = snapshot.docs.map((docs) => {
            return {
              note: docs.data().note,
              id: docs.id,
            };
          });
          setNotes(Object.values(loadedNotes) ?? []);
        });
    };
    getNotes();
  });
```

This function is written 3 times in 3 different components, for notes, todos and upcoming Events. the todos have an extra document field which is the state of completion and upcoming Events have a field for event date.

I also have firebase authentication in my project, I don't know is this matters on not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Where are your useEffect dependencies?  As written, this will run on EVERY render of the component... is that what you intended?

Comment: I didn't use any dependencies actually if it is fetching async around 1 time/second does this count as a document read? For example, does it count as 60 reads per minute?

Comment: It will run on every *render*, which includes *every* change to props or state in the component - and each ```.get()``` as written will count as *multiple* reads.  I think you need to spend more time understanding the lifecycle of react components.

Comment: Thank you, yes turns out my weather api fetches data every second and is causing the component to re-render and causing the high amounts of reading documents.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `get()` on collection references, this loads every document in that collection every time it is requested which is highly excessive on reads. You should be using using `limit(n)` and pagination where needed, and if possible: `source:cache` on documents.

Ideally, you should be using some sort of redux/redis local storage which you add the data too once on app load and read from before making random scraping to Firebase Collections

- https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/firestore/Source
- https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/order-limit-data

Comment: Still I have only one collection and very few documents (a maximum of 4 or 5 documents) which means 34 thousand reads are seriously exaggerated if that is the case.

Comment: You are neglecting how frequently those components can run, those reads are coming from somewhere